# What's the most efficient way to load a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, database, dictionary, pickle

I have what is a Python dictionary of ~1000 entries. A script is going to be called repeatedly that will want to parse a string and see if any keys in the string match. If they do, it will take some action based on the key and the value.

Which of these is faster?

1) Store the dictionary in a MySQL database, and then read the database each time the script is called?

2) Store the dictionary in a Python script and import it every time? (e.g. make a file that contains nothing but the dictionary initialization)

3) Store the dictionary in a text file, and import it every time? (either a flat text file or a pickle serialized data file, using cpickle)

Just looking for a best practice here.

Comment: A 1000 entry dictionary isn't that big.  If you are worried about "load time" why don't you just put your dictionary in a python module and import it once at the beginning of your app?  It will be compiled into a PYC file and be nice and fast after the first time you run it, right?

Comment: As K. says, your dictionary is tiny, so you should probably just load it into memory in a pyc.  However, for actual large dictionaries you should use a database like BDB or MetaKit, not a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a .py Python file that just assigns the dictionary to a name. Save the file. Compile the file to a .pyc then load it as a module when needed by your main Python script.

You get the advantage of keeping a readable textual representation of your dict for maintenance/debug, the speed of loading a .pyc file and the simplicity of it all being standard Python.

Comment: The file will be automatically compiled to a `.pyc` the first time it's imported.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that storing it as a dictionary in a python file and importing into every module that needs it would be the way to go. Can you construct it programmatically?  Either way, the file will only be actually imported once per program execution so it shouldn't be a big deal unless you know that loading it once at the beginning is unacceptable for some reason.

`shelve` could be another way to go here. This would probably be the way to do it if you wanted to go with option (3) It's built on the `anydbm` module. This will probably be slower but will allow you to avoid having the whole thing in memory at once.

In my opinion, both 1) and 3) are right out. The overhead of making the database queries would, in all probability, slow access down dramatically. Option 2) will make it all a simple dict lookup.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can also load a dictionary with whatever (integer numbers in this case) like this:

```
    D = dict(zip(range(100),range(100)))
```